# Set default timeout with publisher confirmations

Tags: java, amqp, spring-amqp

I want to implement example with AMQP publisher confirmations configured with timeout. Something like this:

```
        private final CountDownLatch confirmLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        TransactionResponseFactory processingPeply = (TransactionResponseFactory) processingTransactionTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(
            ContextServer.EXCHANGE_PROCESSING, ContextServer.ROUTING_KEY_PROCESSING_, tf);


        if (processingTransactionTemplate.confirmLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            System.out.println("Confirm received");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Confirm NOT received");
            // add some logic here to resend
        }
```

What is the proper way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

- Add a `RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback` to the template.
- Send the latch in a `CorrelationData` object (subclass) - extra parameter in the send operation.
- In the callback count down the latch.

Bear in mind though, that waiting for confirm after every send will significantly slow down publishing.

It's really intended for publishing a bunch of messages and then later waiting for their confirmations.

Of course, the design depends on your requirements.